# How do I clear a c variable after use to use it again?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

If I send a message over serial the first time it receves the right code it works but after that it stops working.

```
    const unsigned int MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 32;
    const char EMPTY[1] = {'\0'};
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);//bPS
    }

    String readserial(){
      char message[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
      static unsigned int message_pos = 0;
      while (Serial.available() > 0 ){
    
        char inbyte = Serial.read();
        if(inbyte != '\n' && (message_pos < MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH - 1)){
          message[message_pos] = inbyte;
          message_pos += 1;
        } else {
          message[message_pos] = '\0';
          //Serial.println(message);
          return message;
        }
      }
      return EMPTY;
    }
    
    void loop() {
      static String message;
      message = readserial();
    
      if(message == "Hi"){
        Serial.println("Hello");
      }else{
        //Serial.println(message);
      }
    }
```

the output shows hello only if I say Hi first if I put anything else it just doesn't work.
I have tried looking for an answer elsewhere but I am stuck.

Comment: You need to reset `message_pos` back to 0 in the `else` case if you are saying you want to start a new string in that case.

Comment: This is C++, not C.

Comment: @tkausl C++ seems correct even though OP asks "How do I clear a c variable"?

Comment: OP seems to think this is C. This is however code for the Arduino IDE/Toolchain, which compiles it as C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message length `message_pos`isn't being reset to zero. Whatever value it has, the value will be "kept" because you have declared it as `static`.  If you remove the `static`keyword, `message_pos` will be reset to zero *every time* you call `readserial()`.

You can also, as pointed out, set `message_pos`to zero as you return the string.

However, because you don't actually use (or need) `message_pos` as `static` I suggest you simply remove the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to start a new string upon encountering a newline character. That being the case you just need to reset `message_pos` back to 0 in the `else`.

```
if(inbyte != '\n' && (message_pos < MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH - 1)){
    message[message_pos] = inbyte;
    message_pos += 1;
} else {
    message[message_pos] = '\0';
    message_pos = 0;  // <<---- THIS LINE ADDED
    return message;
}
```

Comment: or just remove static from `static unsigned int message_pos = 0;`

Comment: @long.kl That won't work. There is no guarantee that a newline will be read in one iteration of `loop`. Need to continue from the previous `message_pos` whenever `loop` runs to continue filling in the buffer from the last point.

Comment: but if the prograrm call readserial 2 times, the 2nd message var will back to uninitialize value -> author don't want to read serial continuously like you said.

Comment: @long.kl Do you understand that this is Arduino code and do you know how Arduino run time works? The `loop` is called periodically. So the serial data may only have the first character `H` when `readserial` is called. Then the runtime will call `loop` again later. At that point there may be another character available, say `i`. In that case the OP wants the message to continue so that the buffer will contain `Hi`.

Comment: yes, I know the usecase in the arduino code, however in c/c++ when a var go out of its scope it will be destroy. in this case I just want to tell message var 's value will be undefined at second times.